# How to resize form in scale? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, scale

i need that in my form the width is twice the height (1:2) **also when i resize**
How i can do that?
Thanks for help and sorry for my english :)

Comment: WPF, WinForms, or Web form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the [Control.Resize event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize.aspx) -- also

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{   
    Control control = (Control)sender;
    control.Width = control.Height * 2; 
}
```

Comment: So, if I resize only the Width, it is always being reset. If I only resize the height on the other hand it is going to work. As a user, I would find this very confusing. It would be better to check whether or not one of the two is unchanged and then set that based on the changed one.

Answer (score 8):

Check out this post: [Resizing forms while keeping aspect ratio](https://web.archive.org/web/20120212181616/http://www.stoyanoff.info/blog/2010/06/27/resizing-forms-while-keeping-aspect-ratio/).

The key is to respond to the [`WM_SIZING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-sizing) message, it allows you to change the window rectangle.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Necessary to take the window frame width/height into account
        this.chromeWidth = this.Width - this.ClientSize.Width;
        this.chromeHeight = this.Height - this.ClientSize.Height;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 200);
    }

    // ...

    #region Resizer
    private float constantWidth = 2;
    private float constantHeight = 1;

    private int chromeWidth;
    private int chromeHeight;

    // From Windows SDK
    private const int WM_SIZING = 0x214;

    private const int WMSZ_LEFT = 1;
    private const int WMSZ_RIGHT = 2;
    private const int WMSZ_TOP = 3;
    private const int WMSZ_BOTTOM = 6;

    struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SIZING)
        {
            RECT rc = (RECT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(RECT));

            int w = rc.Right - rc.Left - chromeWidth;
            int h = rc.Bottom - rc.Top - chromeHeight;

            switch (m.WParam.ToInt32()) // Resize handle
            {
                case WMSZ_LEFT:
                case WMSZ_RIGHT:
                    // Left or right handles, adjust height
                    rc.Bottom = rc.Top + chromeHeight + (int)(constantHeight * w / constantWidth);
                    break;

                case WMSZ_TOP:
                case WMSZ_BOTTOM:
                    // Top or bottom handles, adjust width
                    rc.Right = rc.Left + chromeWidth + (int)(constantWidth * h / constantHeight);
                    break;

                case WMSZ_LEFT + WMSZ_TOP:
                case WMSZ_LEFT + WMSZ_BOTTOM:
                    // Top-left or bottom-left handles, adjust width
                    rc.Left = rc.Right - chromeWidth - (int)(constantWidth * h / constantHeight);
                    break;

                case WMSZ_RIGHT + WMSZ_TOP:
                    // Top-right handle, adjust height
                    rc.Top = rc.Bottom - chromeHeight - (int)(constantHeight * w / constantWidth);
                    break;

                case WMSZ_RIGHT + WMSZ_BOTTOM:
                    // Bottom-right handle, adjust height
                    rc.Bottom = rc.Top + chromeHeight + (int)(constantHeight * w / constantWidth);
                    break;
            }

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, m.LParam, true);
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: The important thing to note here is that this will happen while the user is dragging the window handle which gives a *much* better experience than responding to the Resize (which happens afterwards)

Answer (score 1):

Use a **TableLayoutControl** to host your other controls. This works similarly to the HTML table.

You add your controls to a cell in the table, and then you can add ColumnStyles and RowStyles in which you can set the width and height of the cells. The measurments can be specified as auto, absolute or percentage. Percentage is the one that you really need here.

You then set this **TableLayoutControl**'s dock to resize with your window, and the cells will get resized *proportionally* according to the percentages you set earlier.

To have the actual components resize as well, you have to set either of their **Dock** or **Anchor** properties. Any configuration that specifies how a control should be resized with respect to the cell it's in will work, e.g. you might want to have the controls resize only vertically in the cell and still remain the same width by setting the control's Anchor property to

```
AnchorStyle.Top | AnchorStyle.Bottom
```

In a nutshell:

- Set how the control will be resized with respect to its cell
- Set how the cells will be resized with respect to the TableLayoutControl (using ColumnStyles and RowStyles)
- Set how the TableLayoutControl will be resized with respect to the form

More information can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb798032.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Register to the resize event and literally do this:

```
this.ClientSize.Width = this.ClientSize.Height * 2;
```

or for the full form size (including borders)

```
this.Size.Width = this.Size.Height * 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use events such as onLoad, onClick and so others, to do resizing on certain conditions. So basically its up to you then.

There is some standard form properties height and width, so you can adjust these properties.

For example:

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int height = 500;
        frmMain.ActiveForm.Height = height;
        frmMain.ActiveForm.Width = height / 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for resize the form below is better one

http://niravdaraniya.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-to-resize-form-in-cnet.html

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.